# OS With Equivalent GUI To Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, gui, desktop-environment

I recently ran Kali Linux Live on my PC just to see what its all about. I've used Mint, MX and Ubuntu in the past, so I wanted to see how Kali is different. Anyway I REALLY like how Kali Linux looks. The interface and colors is quite nice, but Kali is not an OS I want to use daily since I'm not a hacker. Does anyone know of a "normal" Linux OS that looks similar to Kali's GUI? Even if I can recreate it with different environments, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: i tried and tried, but no, i just cannot see what you are looking at .... maybe somebody else can?

Comment: The current version, that comes with `kali-linux-2020.2-live-amd64.iso` has the XFCE desktop environment (not the crude one, but tweaked by the developers of KALI) The XFCE (actually `xfce4` set for program packages) is considered easy to configure to make it look like you want. Several other Linux distros maintain flavours with XFCE, for example Xubuntu (flavour of Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment) and Ubuntu Studio. - XFCE is also considered light-weight, suitable also for older computers, and works very fast on new computers.

Comment: So I guess all you need to do is to take the Kali XFCE configuration, and copy it to some other distro where you install xfce?

Comment: @sudodus that sounds like it could be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XFCE

The current version of Kali Linux, that comes with

```
kali-linux-2020.2-live-amd64.iso
```

has **the XFCE desktop environment** (not the crude one, but tweaked by the developers of Kali).

- XFCE (actually the `xfce4` set for program packages) is considered easy to configure to make it look like you want. Several other Linux distros maintain flavours with XFCE, for example Xubuntu (flavour of Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment) and Ubuntu Studio.
- XFCE is also considered light-weight, suitable for older computers, and works very fast on new computers.
- As suggested in a comment by @dirkt, you can take the Kali XFCE configuration, and copy it to some other distro where you install xfce (or where there is already XFCE).